# Ignoring tests until called for in Maven/Junit?

Tags: maven, junit, categories

Is there a way to setup a Maven project to run to ignore a collection of tests by default unless a specific system variable is present?

For example, if I run the following:

```
mvn clean install
```

A certain collection of tests are not executed as part of the build.  If I execute the build in this way:

```
mvn clean install -DrunAllTests
```

The tests that are ignored by default in the standard build are also executed.

I know I can do this using TestNG, but I would prefer to stay with JUnit for now.  I also tried using the Junit Categories feature, but could not get the tests to be ignored by default.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include tests for execution you can add the following configuration for maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<configuration>
   <includes>
      <include>**/SomeTests*.java</include>
   </includes>
</configuration>
```

So, you can use this together with Maven profiles, and extract/enable your additional tests in a spacial profile. For example:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>allTests</id>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/SomeOtherTests*.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
     </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then maven command would look like this:

```
mvn clean install -PallTests
```

If you prefer to use properties, you can add activation section to the allTests profile and activate it based on given property.

Comment: I set up by general build to exclude some of the tests, and a profile to include them.  If I run a "mvn clean install", the tests are excluded which is what I want.  If I run "mvn clean install -PallTests", the tests are still excluded which is not what I want.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [Category](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/categories/Category.html) feature of JUnit together with [excludeGroups](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludedGroups) of Maven's Surefire plugin.

Comment: I had looked in to that, but it is unclear to me how to include the excludedGroups at runtime.  I concluded that I would have to create two profiles, one that included all tests and one that included all but the ones I want to exclude.  This would mean at runtime I would have to specify which profile to run, which does not meet my goals.  I know I can set one of them to default, but I have other profiles for other purposes which would cause problems.  Am I incorrect?